# iOS 11 UITextField - override drawText(in rect) not being called

Tags: swift, ios11

```
class TestTextField: UITextField {
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
      let upperText = self.text?.uppercased()
      upperText?.draw(in: rect)
    }
}
```

Hello, small question if I may ask:

Simple class extending UITextField, overriding drawText(..) method.
Works under iOS 10, override not being called in iOS 11.

As tomorrow, iOS11 should be announced, some questions would be:

- is there any list of bugs still open for iOS11?
- is there any workaround for this?

note: iOS11 beta 10, clean new project

Comment: note: iOS11 beta 11, clean new project

Comment: Add your note to the post, rather than as a comment. Click on `edit`

Comment: Also when overriding textRect(forBounds:), the returned height is ignored. Only the top is used. It's a bug is ios 11. Seems to be in the way to be fixed in xcode 9.1